# What does a closed 3-brane look like?

Tags: spacetime-dimensions, branes

A closed 2-brane looks like a donut, or in scientific terms, a torus. This is a three-dimensional object. I came across this diagram in a book, "The Little Book of String Theory". A torus is a three-dimensional object, so a closed 3-brane would be a fourth-dimensional object. The author provided an image of a closed 2-brane, but refused to give an answer for an image of a closed 3-brane, saying simply that it was too difficult to draw. I cannot find any pictures of one on the internet that clearly explain it. Has anybody found a picture of a closed 3-brane that they can provide? Thank you.

Comment: A closed 2-brane does not have to be a torus. It can be any 2-manifold. So the simplest possibility is just a sphere.

Comment: @MitchellPorter That also occurred to me as well. Would a four-dimensional sphere be just a welded bunch of three-dimensional spheres?

Comment: That grow from a point, to a maximum, then back to a point (think of how ordinary sphere goes from pole to equator to pole).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [this youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=1&v=sdnzcEO-FcY), which animates a slice-through of a 4D torus. It may or may not be topologically equivalent to what you are talking about.